# updating subversion repository gave zero conflicts

Tags: svn

I am using tortoise svn client. I have checked out a file.now i made some changes ,then after file has got red warning symbol indicating changes are made. Now i have tried to do SVN-Update without comitting.I expected some conflicts but this has not given me any warning/error. Is this normal behavior.Any one explain please.

Orginal file content : ABC

After modification ,file has this content : pqr

Comment: Why do you expect a conflict?

Comment: i initially thought if we do changes in working copy and no changes in remote file , then when we do svn update it gives conflicts(Expected it will compare the local changed working copy)
but later realised only if there are changes in remote file and line changes are different then only we get conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were no changes in the repository version which were made on the same line(s) as your change, then there is no conflict to report.

The working copy knows what you originally checked out (or last updated) from the repository, including the revision you checked out from. When performing an update, if there were no changes made in the repository between the revision you checked out and the current latest (the `HEAD` revision), then there is nothing to report. If there *are* changes between the revision you checked out and `HEAD`, the changes are downloaded, the new version compared against the changes in your working copy, and if you have changed any content that was also changed in the repository a conflict will be flagged.

Comment: Thanks. it was helpful